# using value of < input > in httpRequest with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a form contain fields with html and i would like to put values in the httprequest with javascript

```
Code : <input  id='code' type='numerique' >
Name : <input  id='name' type='text' >

<input type=button class="btn btn-large btn-primary"  value="Search" onclick=Search(); /> 


<div id='content'>
code of result search
</div>

<script>
 function Search()
 {
  $('#content').load('frontController?serviceId=SearchModal&classeName=com.bfi.ref.rol.Client&eventName=onSearch&serviceInstanceId=" + serviceInstanceId +" ');
    }


<script>
```

Comment: What problem are you having doing this? Can't you use `#("#code").val()` to get the input value?

Comment: `type='numerique'` doesn't look like a valid type; HTML attributes don't get translated into other languages, it should be `type='number'`.

Comment: Your quotes aren't correct. You started the `.load()` argument with single quote, but ended it with double quote before the `+` operator.

Comment: thks evrybody i found the solution
<input type=button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" id="add"  value="Search" onclick=Search(); /> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
       $('#content').load('frontController?serviceId=SearchModal&classeName=com.bfi.ref.rol.Client&eventName=onSearch&serviceInstanceId=" + serviceInstanceId +" '), {
           name: $("#name").val(), 
           code: $("#code").val()
       });
    });
});

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer.

Comment: okiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii i'm sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thks evrybody i found the solution

```
<input type=button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" id="add" value="Search" onclick=Search(); /> 

<scirpt>
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#add").click(function() { 
$('#content').load('frontController?serviceId=SearchModal&classeName=com.bfi.ref‌​.rol.Client&eventName=onSearch&serviceInstanceId=" + serviceInstanceId +" '), 
{ name: $("#name").val(), 
code: $("#code").val() }); 
}); 
});
</scirpt>
```